# CentOS/Postfix cannot receive or send emails to external domains

Tags: email, postfix, azure

I run CentOS 6 server on Windows Azure cloud. Plesk 11 installed. And the problem is that I cant use webmail service since it doesn't send or receive emails. Port 25 looks closed from [MXTools](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=scan%3a137.117.129.207&run=toolpage)

**Things I have tried**

- I opened necessary ports on Azure: http://i42.tinypic.com/53790z.png
- I tried adding a relayhost to /etc/postfix/main.cf
- I tried to disable iptables

What can be blocking that port?

Weird thing is that Plesk can send me mails (like updates on server and such).

Comment: Something external to the server probably.. most likely a firewall. You can configure webmail to send via port 465 to an external relay possibly.

Comment: I tried with my Mailjet account to send emails with port 25 and also with 587, no help. It says in maillog: connection timed out.

Comment: That's rough, I guess they may have a policy in place that says no outgoing mail. Maybe you should speak to your account manager..

Comment: I have been trying things for 2 days now. No luck. I think I will go with a SMTP service like Zoho.. (Cheaper than Google Apps)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things up.
Relayhost has no connection with incoming mail.
Outgoing mail: you said that works (plesk updates/etc mails).
Incoming: I'm not an Azure user, but that looks good. Maybe you didn't disable iptables properly, what does `iptables -L -n` show ?

Comment: No, both sending and receiving doesn't work. Webmail doesn't send emails. I will post iptables tomorrow, I dont have access right now.

Comment: `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:68

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`

Comment: That looks ok.A `telnet ip 25` from outside could help if you have telnet. Or maybe recheck with mxtoolbox, and after check copy any relevant info from /opt/psa/var/log/maillog here (edit you first post so formatting preserved), maybe a `tail -30 /opt/psa/var/log/maillog` over ssh .